# Python unable to recognize the path

Tags: python

```
def whatNumIsThis(filePath):
    matchedAr = []
    loadExamps = open("C:/Users/p.de.falco/Desktop/images/numArEx.txt", "r").read()
    loadExamps = loadExamps.split("\n")

    i = Image.open(filePath)
    iar = np.array(i)
    iarl = iar.tolist()

    inQuestion = str(iarl)
    for eachExample in loadExamps:
        if len(eachExample) > 3:
            splitEx = eachExample.split("::")
            currentNum = splitEx[0]
            currentAr = splitEx[1]

            eachPixEx = currentAr.split("],")
            eachPixInQ = inQuestion.split("],")
            x = 0
            while x < len(eachPixEx):
                if eachPixEx[x] == eachPixInQ[x]:
                    matchedAr.append(int(currentNum))
                x += 1

    print(matchedAr)
    x = Counter(matchedAr)
    print(x)


whatNumIsThis("C:/Users/p.de.falco/Desktop/images/test.png")
```

Hi, this is a part of a bigger code. it gives to me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/p.de.falco/PycharmProjects/test_1/detect3.py", line 30, in <module>
    whatNumIsThis('C:/Users/p.de.falco/Desktop/images/test.png')
  File "C:/Users/p.de.falco/PycharmProjects/test_1/detect3.py", line 3, in whatNumIsThis
    loadExamps = open('C:/Users/p.de.falco/Desktop/images/numArEx.txt', 'r').read()
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/p.de.falco/Desktop/images/numArEx.txt'
```

I put the path in the same way of other paths that i put in the code, but in this case it is not able to find files. I'm using pycharm and anaconda3, anyone know how to fix this problem? thank you in adavance!

Comment: Well, are you sure that file actually exists? Considering it's a `txt` file in a directory called `images`..?

Comment: Sidenote: Instead of doing `.read()` followed by `split("\n")`, you can also just do `.readlines()`

Comment: Windows doesn't display file extensions by default, so are you sure the file is named `numArEx.txt` and not `numArEx.txt.txt` or the like?

Comment: May be you have to use: open(r"C:/Users/p.de.falco/Desktop/images/numArEx.txt", "r").read(), if there is file inside directory then it works fine.

Comment: I tried all of yours suggestion but nothing works... the file exist for shure, i really don't understand this error....

Comment: Try looking at the output of `os.listdir("C:/Users/p.de.falco/Desktop/images")` and see if you can find the string `"numArEx.txt"` in it.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: The difference is that `readlines` includes the line endings, while `split` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like your file does not exists on given path 

You can verify either file exists before opening it via this way:

```
import os.path
os.path.exists('C:/Users/p.de.falco/Desktop/images/numArEx.txt')
```

it will return True if file exists there else false

hope this helps!

Cheers!

Comment: the files exist, i put your code on pycharm but it finish with error code: 0, what does it means?

Comment: You need to put os.path.exists.... with if to actually get True or False.

Comment: `if os.path.exists('C:/Users/p.de.falco/Desktop/images/numArEx.txt'):
   print("file exsits")`Like this!

Comment: I did it but same result... Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: if is not getting true! Means file is not there or path is not correct!
Try r in the start to treat string literally
 `if os.path.exists(r'C:/Users/p.de.falco/Desktop/images/numArEx.txt'): print("file exsits")`